# magento pear file 1.4.1.1

Tags: php, magento, upgrade, pear

I’m trying to upgrade 1.4.1.1 to 1.4.2 with sshd (cygwin, on a windows 7 machine -> Xampp -> cygwin. 
The problem I have is with the command:

$ ./pear mage-setup

Resulting in:

```
$ ./pear mage-setup . 
Running initial setup… 
Could not open input file: /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/mysite/downloader/pearlib/php/pearmage.php 
Could not open input file: /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/mysite/downloader/pearlib/php/pearmage.php
```

etc.

I think the pear file is not complete. The first lines of the file are now:

```
'#!/bin/sh

'#REPLACE with your PHP5 binary path (example: /usr/local/php5/bin/php ) 
MAGE_PEAR_PHP_BIN="/cygdrive/c/xampp/php/php"

PEAR_PATH="downloader/pearlib"
```

Who has any ideas or a work around?

Thanks in advance! 
Larz

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was making sure that the Magento installation's path does not contain any spaces.

So for example if you have installed Magento in the following path: */Users/MyName/Web/Magento/My Magento Shop/* change that path to: */Users/MyName/Web/Magento/My-Magento-Shop/* and it should work.

I also had to execute the command with *sudo* like this:

```
sudo ./pear mage-setup .
```